# Separator data received via post request

Tags: php, javascript

My problem is: I get through a post request the variable "data" in Javascript, like this:

```
var data = name1 text1 name2 text2 name3 text3;
```

How do I divide each data element in a variable like this:

```
var group1 =  name1 - text1;
var group2 =  name2 - text2;
var group3 =  name3 - text3;
```

Then I decided to put a separator in php, the character "-" in each group (variable) that would form, and then deal with the javascript function "split()" the string. The problem is that in the text there could also be the "-" character and any other character, how do I saparare as in example without using JSON? I control both the server side (PHP) or client-side (Javascript).

Comment: If you can control the format of `data`, I'd suggested you to deliver it rather as an array than a string.

Comment: Is this possible? The variable "data" is the server response from the POST request. How do I get an array without using JSON?

Comment: `var data = name1 text1 name2 text2 name3 text3;` is not valid JavaScript, what are you *really* doing? Show some minimal code that actually works so that we know what you're doing, and thus can answer your question without guessing.

Comment: So, name1 and text2 are simple text, i would like separate this text as in example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a wide assumption about what your php code looks like, since you so conveniently left it out. I imagine it looks like this (off the top of my head, may not actually work):

```
$response = '';
mysql_query('select name, text from mytable');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
    $response = $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['text'] . ' ' .$response;
}
echo $response;
```

You should instead respond with an object like this:

```
$response = array();
mysql_query('select name, text from mytable');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
    $response[$row['name']] = $row['text'];
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Then, in your javascript, it will look like this:

```
var data = {"name1": "text1", "name2": "text2", "name3": "text3"};
```

And you can create your groups like this:

```
var groups = [];
for (var name in data) {
    groups.push(name + " - " + data[name]);
}
```

to create an array of those groups you wanted.